# insert $id into form values array

Tags: php, sql

How can I insert values from both a form and an external called value?  Here is what I have so far :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO workorder (name, date, installer, salesman, category, status) values('$id', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
```

$id is a value called from a seperate php page, and returns a valid value
the other values are called using an array :

$q->execute(array($date,$installer,$salesman,$category,$status));

I get no error, and the array executes and inserts ok, but the $id is not inserted as "name" in the table.  Any Ideas?

@baroni :
did so, and the code still does not insert a value for $id.  I know that $id has a value, I used firefox web dev tools to get the $id value(53) corresponding with the other page

@baroni : 
$id is an integer, called with the following code from a different page :

```
echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="createworkorder.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Add Workorder</a>';
```

I do not want to set $id as a different number, i want to keep the number from the other page(same as customer.id table)

Comment: try to echo $sql; Use this SQL in MySQL (for example). Does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

If $id is a string

```
$id = "myname";
$sql = "INSERT INTO workorder (name, date, installer, salesman, category, status) values('$id', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
```

If $id is an integer

```
$id = 123;
$sql = "INSERT INTO workorder (name, date, installer, salesman, category, status) values($id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
```

Comment: tried to do that, but it just returns to the header after completion

Comment: ID is an integer, how do i change the code accordingly?

Comment: added code explanation, after trying and failing above suggestion

Comment: Code that retrieves $id from other page :  $id = null;
 if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
 }
 
 if ( null==$id ) {
  header("Location: customers.php");
 }